# ドキュメントに従いましたが、「SNMPv1 / SNMPv2c読み取り/書き込みアクセスコミュニティ名」を続行できません。

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10

ドキュメントに従いましたが、「SNMPv1 / SNMPv2c読み取り/書き込みアクセスコミュニティ名」を続行できません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実際、 http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu に従って、次のようにWindowsとLinuxにSNMPエージェントをインストールしました。

1. My Linux:
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. My Windows:
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうやってSNMP agentでSNMPに対するセキュリティの脅威を研究できますか。どうもありがとうございます！

Comment: ディレクトリやファイルが、どのような構造になっているのか判らないので具体的な助言は出来ませんが、とにかく"No such file or directory"というエラーメッセージが出るのは、ディレクトリの構造が間違えているか、質問者がディレクトリの構造を理解できていないからだと思われます。
自分のホームディレクトリの下にProjectsディレクトリを作るところから、正しく作業を行えましたか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。 ここで質問するのは初めてなので、調べてみます。